# Asymptotic difference between a function and its binomial average

Tags: real-analysis, binomial-coefficients, asymptotics, average

The origin of this question is the identity
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} H_k = 2^n \left(H_n - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k 2^k}\right),$$
where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number.

Dividing by $2^n$, we have
$$2^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} H_k = H_n - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k 2^k}.$$

The sum on the left can now be interpreted as a weighted average of the harmonic numbers through $H_n$ -- where the weights, of course, are the binomial coefficients.  Thus the difference between $H_n$ and its "binomial average" (I'm guessing there's no term for this) is
$$H_n - 2^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} H_k =  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k 2^k}.$$

The sum on the right is known to converge to $\ln 2$ as $n \to \infty$.  (Substitute $-\frac{1}{2}$ into the Maclaurin series for $\ln (1+x)$.)

This leads me to my question:

> Can we classify nonnegative functions $f(n)$ for which 
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(f(n) - 2^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} f(k) \right)$$ is finite and nonzero?

It would seem that if $f$ increases sufficiently rapidly, then the limit would be $\infty$.  This is the case with both $f(n) = a^n$ and $f(n) = n$.  If $f$ decreases or is constant, then the limit is zero.  If $f$ has basically logarithmic growth, then it seems the limit would behave as $H_n$.  But can this be proved?  And what about other sublinear, increasing functions?

Comment: I agree that logarithmic growth is what you need. The "binomial average" of $f(n)$ should be about $f(n/2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f(n)$ must be $\Theta (\log n)$.  **Update:** As Didier Piau points out in the comments to the [question after I asked it on Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46777/asymptotic-difference-between-a-function-and-its-binomial-average), we can say something stronger: $\frac{f(n)}{\log_2 n} \to L$ as $n \to \infty$.  See the update at the end of the argument.

Suppose, for some positive $L$ (the negative case is similar), $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(f(n) - 2^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} f(k) \right) = L.$$
Thus $$f(n) = L + r(n) + 2^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} f(k)$$ for some function $r(n)$ such that $r(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  This gives us a recurrence relation for $f(n)$.  Since $r(n) \to 0$, $L + r(n) > 0$ for all sufficiently large $n$.  So, for all sufficiently large $n$, there exist positive constants $C$ and $D$ such that $C < L + r(n) < D$.  Since the initial terms in the function eventually become negligible in determining the value of $f(n)$ via the recurrence relation, there exist functions $g(n)$ and $h(n)$ such that for all sufficiently large $n$, $g(n) \leq f(n) \leq h(n)$ and $g(n)$ and $h(n)$ satisfy 
$$g(n) = C + 2^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} g(k),$$
$$h(n) = D + 2^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} h(k).$$

So the problem reduces to showing that $g(n)$ and $h(n)$ are $\Theta (\log n)$.  The argument is the same for both.

There are some different ways to do this; my favorite is to interpret the $g(n)$ recurrence probabilistically.  Suppose we start at time $g(0)$, we flip a set of $n$ coins simultaneously each round, and it takes $C$ time units to do one round of flips.  When a coin turns up heads for the first time, we cease flipping it.  Let $T(n)$ be the time at which the last coin to achieve its first head does so.  To find $E[T(n)]$, condition on the number of coins that achieve heads in the first round of flips.  This yields $$E[T(n)] = C + 2^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} E[T(n-k)] = C + 2^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} E[T(k)].$$  Thus $g(n) = E[T(n)]$.

Another way to view $T(n)$ is that it is $g(0) + C M_n$, where $M_n = \max\{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\}$ and the $X_i$'s are independent and identically distributed geometric $(1/2)$ random variables.  (Each geometric random variable models the first time a head appears.)  Thus $g(n) = g(0) + C E[M_n]$.  It is known that $\frac{H_n}{\log 2} \leq E[M_n] \leq \frac{H_n}{\log 2} + 1$ and, more precisely, that $E[M_n]$ is logarithmically summable to $\frac{H_n}{\log 2} + \frac{1}{2}$.  (See, for example, Bennett Eisenberg's paper "On the expectation of the maximum of IID geometric random variables," *Statistics and Probability Letters*  78 (2008) 135-143.  See also this MO question, "[What is the Expected Maximum out of a Sample (size $n$) from a Geometric Distribution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41604/what-is-the-expected-maximum-out-of-a-sample-size-n-from-a-geometric-distributi/)?")

Thus $g(n) = \frac{C}{\log 2} \log n + O(1)$, which means that $h(n) = \frac{D}{\log 2} \log n + O(1)$ and $f(n) = \Theta (\log n)$.

**Update:** Given $\epsilon > 0$, if we take take $C > 0$ such that $L - \epsilon \leq C < L$ and $D = L + \epsilon$, this argument shows that 
$$L - \epsilon + O\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right) \leq \frac{f(n)}{\log_2 n} \leq L + \epsilon + O\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right).$$

Thus, as $n \to \infty$, $\frac{f(n)}{\log_2 n} \to L.$

For some other ideas that pertain to this result, including what are effectively some alternative derivations, see Pradipta's recent MO question, "[Coin Flipping and a Recurrence Relation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55625/coin-flipping-and-a-recurrence-relation)".  In fact, reading Pradipta's question and some of its answers gave me the ideas needed to construct this argument!  So, thanks go to Pradipta, Didier Piau, Emil Jeřábek, and Louigi Addario-Berry.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea that might lead somewhere.  Let $F(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{f(n)}{n!} x^n$, let $g(n) = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose n-k} f(k)$, and let $G(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{g(n)}{n!} x^n$.  Then it's not hard to see that $G(x) = e^{\frac{x}{2}} F \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)$, so we are looking for functions $F$ such that

$$F(x) - e^{\frac{x}{2}} F \left( \frac{x}{2} \right) = A(x)$$

for some $A(x)$ with Taylor coefficients tending to some nonzero limit.  Let $H(x) = e^x F(x)$.  Now we want 

$$H(x) - H \left( \frac{x}{2} \right) = e^{-x} A(x).$$

This condition is easier to work with on the left now but harder to work with on the right.

Comment: Thanks, Qiaochu.  This is a nice formulation of the problem in terms of exponential generating functions and gives another line of attack.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick and rough approach:

It seems probable to me that the particular weights of the averaging are not important, that things would be similar with a (eg) uniform averaging. Assuming this, in the continuous, a simple analogy would be

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty } f(x) -\frac{\int_0^x f(x) dx }{x} = \lim_{x \to \infty }f(x) - \frac{F(x)}{x} = k \hspace{1cm}$  with $f(x) >0 $ and  $0 <k <\infty$

And $f(x) = a \log(x) + b  $  (or any function that grows logarithmically) fits the bill. And, in particular, the harmonic numbers, grows in this way.

Comment: You may be right that the particular weights of the averaging are not important, but I think I would need to see a proof of it before being convinced.  (That might make for a good, separate math.SE question, actually. :) )

Comment: The weights of the averaging matter. Note that, for large $n$, the analogue of the binomial sum applied to $f$ is more like $f(x/2)$ than like the integral of $f$ on $(0,x)$ normalized by $x$. This is because a binomial random variable of parameters $(n,\frac12)$ concentrates around $\frac12n$ rather than becoming spread out over the interval $(0,n)$.

Comment: @Didier: yes, i saw that - i first tried to write the same equations as a convolution with a gaussian, but I prefered this simplification of a simplification. I don't think it changes the law of growth. We could also write the other extreme aproximation (a delta centered at x/2 instead of a uniform) as `f(x) - f(x/2) ~ k` , and we also get `f(x) ~ log(x)`